# Using makefile to run on terminal

Tags: c, makefile

```
 testFile: test2.c
      gcc -o testFile test2.c -I.
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. testFile takes in two arguments, so I supply it with testFile 3 4

That should produce a result but it says testFile is not a command. What the hell do I do? I want to be able to type testFile to run it. What do I need to change in the makefile to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile is fine; it will build a program called `testFile` out of a source file called `test2.c`.  (The `-I.` is a bit weird, but not wrong.)

Your problem is that the current working directory is not on your `PATH` ([and it shouldn't be](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)).  Use `./testFile` to run your program.

Comment: I am doing an assignment and as part of the requirements my inputs need to be testFile a b

Comment: That's a bizarre requirement; can you explain more about that?

Comment: The description gives examples of input and the input like testFile 2 3 testFile 5 6

Comment: Well, that will work if you put `.` on the `PATH`.  Don't do that, though.